# How to translate templates in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

**UPDATED**
NOW I try to do this in my app (thx to Akshat)

//common

```
LANG = 'ru';
Dictionary = new Meteor.Collection("dictionary");

//if server
    Meteor.startup(function () {
    if (Dictionary.find().count() === 0) {
        // code to fill the Dictionary
    }
    });


    Meteor.publish('dictionary', function () {
        return Dictionary.find();
    });
//endif
```

//client

```
t = function(text) {
    if (typeof Dictionary === 'undefined') return text;
    var res = Dictionary.find({o:text}).fetch()[0];
    return res && res.t;
}

    Meteor.subscribe('dictionary', function(){ 
      document.title = t('Let the game starts!'); 
    });

    Template.help.text = t('How to play');
```

//html

```
<body>
  {{> help}}
</body>


<template name="help">
    {{text}}
</template>
```

Still doesn't work as we wanted: when templates are rendered Dictionary was undefined. But`t('How to play')` in console works perfectly )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript variables aren't shared between the client and server reactively. You have to use a Meteor Collection to store your data e.g

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    var Dictionary = new Meteor.Collection("dictionary");

    if(Dictionary.find().count() == 0) {
    //If the 'dictionary collection is empty (count ==0) then add stuff in

        _.each(Assets.getText(LANG+".txt").split(/\r?\n/), function (line) {
            // Skip comment lines
            if (line.indexOf("//") !== 0) {
                var split = line.split(/ = /);
                DICTIONARY.insert({o: split[0], t:split[1]});
            }
        });
    }

}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    var Dictionary = new Meteor.Collection("dictionary");

    Template.help.text = function() {
        return Dictionary.find({o:'Let the game starts!'});
    }
}
```

In the above i'm assuming you have the `autopublish` package in (its in by default when you create a package so this shouldn't really bother you, but just in case you removed)

With your document title you would have to use a slightly different implementation because remember the data wouldn't be downloaded at the time `Meteor.startup` is run, since the html and javascript are downloaded first & the data is empty, then the data comes in slowly (and then reactively fills the data up)

Comment: DICTIONARY.insert({o: split[0], t:split[1]});  i replace with Dictionary.insert({o: split[0], t:split[1]}); but on the client side Dictionary.find().count() is still zer0

Comment: Did you remove autopublish? Also where are you running `Dictionary.find().count()`? If it is anywhere in the initial running code (not in a template helper) it will return 0 because the data is not yet available to the client when its being run (it arrives some few milliseconds later)

Comment: yeap, after i added publish and subscribe, my collection was transfered, find({o: smth}) works. to get property t I use .fetch()[0]
THANKS

Comment: Still doesn't work as we wanted: when templates are rendered Dictionary was undefined.

Comment: Could you share a bit more code, i'm not sure how your text file is structured either, also instead of `.fetch()[0]` you can use `findOne()` what do you get in your browser javascript console when you run `Dictionary.find().fetch()`?

Comment: I see the problem its your `t` function. Use just `t = function(text) { return Dictionary.findOne({o:text}) || text }` Meteor needs it to run once even without data to know what is reactive in it. When the data comes in itll update the content automatically

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Dictionary is not defined" in this case

Comment: i think we should rerender all templates in Meteor.subscribe callback

Comment: This is happening because of the file loading order, `common.js` is being loaded after the client js, place your `common.js` in the root directory in a directory called `/lib`. Stuff in `lib` will always load before everything else

Comment: cool, it's better, t = function(text) {
    var res = Dictionary.findOne({o:text});
    return res && res.t || text;
} but templates still are non reactive =\

Comment: I'm not sure why that is this time, How are you displaying it to screen (in html)? What are you using the reactivity for do you edit the languages while they're running?

Comment: Works this: Template.help.text = function(){
  var text = 'How to play';
  var res = Dictionary.findOne({o:text});
  return res && res.t || text;
} But dont  Template.help.text = t('How to play'); How to fix it?